# Bypassing agreement prompt for DiskUsage.exe?

Tags: windows, disk-space, disk-utility, sysinternals

I am running du.exe on a remote windows machine and do not want to have to access the remote machine's desktop, but the first run of du.exe is requiring an acceptance of the agreement which would require accessing the desktop and clicking.  Is there a way to bypass or automatically accept this?

`c:\utils\du -l 3 -c -q c:\ > c:\utils\du3.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is there a way to bypass or automatically accept the `du` licence agreement?

If you have access to the registry on the remote machine then run the following command:

```
reg.exe ADD "HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\Disk Usage" /v EulaAccepted /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

There are similar commands for other SysInternals utilities.

Running the following to accept the licence for all of the utilities:

```
reg.exe ADD HKCU\Software\Sysinternals /v EulaAccepted /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg.exe ADD HKU\.DEFAULT\Software\Sysinternals /v EulaAccepted /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Source [Work around Sysinternals license pop-ups - Peter Hahndorf](https://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/post/2010/03/07/WorkAroundSysinternalsLicensePopups)

Comment: Thanks David!  This works great.  Thanks for the information and the reference URL.

After verifying the entry in the register and since I'm doing this remotely I'm just needing to send this:

`reg.exe ADD "HKU\.DEFAULT\Software\Sysinternals\Du" /v EulaAccepted /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`